# Magento 2: create object of other class as Psr or session in Plugins

Tags: magento2, plugin

I have created a Plugin to add custom buttons in grid, based on admin user login. If super admin logins all buttons will be displayed else for other admin users button will be removed, so that they can not edit.

```
<type name="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\Toolbar">
    <plugin name="restrict_admin_user" type="Singh\Import\Plugin\Toolbar" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
```

Code for Toolbar.php

```
class Toolbar
{public function beforePushButtons(
ToolbarContext $toolbar,
    AbstractBlock $context,
    ButtonList $buttonList,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $log,
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession){
if ($authSession->isLoggedIn()){
        $log->debug("user name=".$authSession->getUser()->getUserName());
    }
}}
```

I have run the compile also

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

But it throws exception

```
main.CRITICAL: exception 'Exception' with message 'Recoverable Error: Argument 4 passed to Singh\Import\Plugin\Toolbar::beforePushButtons() must implement interface Psr\Log\LoggerInterface, none given
```

same exception for `\Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session`
So how I can use log and other class object?

Answer (score 0):

Replace following code

```
namespace Singh\Import\Plugin;


class Toolbar
{

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $log;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session
     */
    protected $authSession;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $log
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $log
    ) {
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
        $this->log = $log;
    }

    public function beforePushButtons(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\Toolbar $subject,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\ButtonList $buttonList
        ) {

        if ($this->authSession->isLoggedIn()){
            $this->log->debug("user name=".$this->authSession->getUser()->getUserName());
        }
    }
}
```

Delete **var/generation/***